# Where is .class defined in Java? (Is it a variable or what?)

Tags: java

There are 2 ways to get a class's `Class` object.

1. Statically:

   ```
   Class cls = Object.class;
   ```
2. From an instance:

   ```
   Object ob = new Object();  
   Class cls = ob.getClass();
   ```

Now my question is `getClass()` is a method present in the `Object` class,
but what is `.class`? Is it a variable? If so then where is it defined in Java?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's implemented internally and called a **class literal** which is handled by the JVM.

The Java Language Specification specifically mentions the term "token" for it.

So `.class` is more than a variable, to be frank it is not a variable at all. At a broader level you can consider it as a keyword or *token*.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type `void`, **followed by a '`.`' and the token `class`.**
>
> A class literal evaluates to the `Class` object for the named type (or for `void`) as defined by the defining class loader (§12.2) of the class of the current instance.

Comment: Just a side note, `Object.getClass()` is defined with the `native` keyword, so it's also handled by JVM. Both ways probably share the same native implementation.

Answer (score 0):

That information resides in the class 'file', although classes need not have a physical .class file in the file system. The JVM takes care of making it available from the class definition, as the other answer states.

See also:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-4.html